# How to top-align TEXTAREA and TEXT-input controls in flexitem?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

First I used the flex: property to make two adjacent flexitems grow and shrink when the browser window was resized. That worked.

Then I put a TEXTAEA element into the second dynamic flexitem. That worked fine.

Added a single-line TEXT input element next to the textarea and observed that the bottom line of the text input element aligned with the bottom line of the textarea, but I want the top lines of the two elements to align. How can I do that without scripting using CSS only?

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.verttop {
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.dimen {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.placeholder {
  background-color: khaki;
  width: 300px;
}

.bs1 {
  background-color: green;
  width: 20px;
}

.bs2 {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: cyan;
}

.bs3 {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: red;
}

.bs4 {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="placeholder dimen"></div>
  <div class="bs1 dimen"></div>
  <div class="bs2 dimen"></div>
  <div class="bs3">
    <textarea rows="10" cols="18">This is a fairly     lengthy and annoyingly meaningless sentence.
          </textarea>
    <input class="verttop" type="text" value="Hello">
  </div>
  <div class="bs4 dimen"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.verttop { vertical-align: top; }` will top align the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by making .bs3 flex and aligning its items.

```
.bs3 {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

Comment: Barlowe Beautiful! Simple! Did not know 'display: flex;' can be nested like this. I must have missed it when reading the spec, or it is not there.

Comment: no problem - you can accept the answer if it's resolved